# how to set multiple colour filter simultaneously in macOS?

Tags: macos, colors, accessibility

I want to setup multiple colour filter, such as having colour tint and monochrome at the same time. The accessibility only let me setup either but not both.

This can be achieved on iOS when having display with colour filter and then add a zoom filter using grey scale but such option is not available on the desktop os.

How do I achieve this?